# Passing Values from Checkboxes from View to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble passing data from my view to my controller. I am using checkboxes. For my view, I created a class that takes in all my checkboxes (Mon-Fri) and putting them into a list (so I can use the data someplace else). My problem is that when I debug and click the checkboxes on the website, the code does not change whether I click the checkbox or not, so my code doesn't recognize the checkbox data

I'm not sure if I have implemented the View incorrectly but any help to the right direction would be appreciated !

ViewModel:

```
public List<cDay> _cDays = new List <cDay>();

public List<cDay> cDays
{
   get {return _cDays;}
   set {_cDays = value;}
}

public class cDay
{
    public bool Monday { get; set; }
    public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
    public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
    public bool Thursday { get; set; }
    public bool Friday { get; set; }
}
```

CSHtml file:

```
@Html.Label("M")
@Html.CheckBox("Monday", false, new { @class = "availability" })
// this is basically the same code for Tuesday-Friday as well.

'<label for="M">M</label> +
'<input class="availability" id="Monday" name="Monday" type="checkbox" value="true">' +
'input name="Monday" type="hidden" value="false">'
// this is basically the same code for Tuesday-Friday, but the "name" corresponds to each day
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(string inputValue, Model viewModel)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    // 

}
```

Comment: Try Html.CheckBoxFor() although if you can, I'd advise to use the new tags in .NET. @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Monday)

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use the following data model:

```cs
public class DaysViewModel  
{
    public List<CDay> Days { get; set; } = new List<CDay>();
}

public class CDay
{
    public CDay()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
        Selected = false;
    }

    public CDay(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Selected = false; 
    }      

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use the default ASP.NET MVC data binding without a JS support:

```
@model Models.DaysViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home"))
{   
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
    for(int i=0; i < Model.Days.Count; i++)  
    {
        <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.CheckBox("Days[" + i + "].Selected", Model.Days[i].Selected)   
        @Html.Hidden("Days[" + i + "].Name", Model.Days[i].Name)
        <span>@Model.Days[i].Name </span>   
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

And on the server side:

```cs
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var model = new DaysViewModel();
    model.Days.AddRange( new List<CDay> {
            new CDay("Monday"),
            new CDay("Tuesday"),
            new CDay("Wednesday"),
            new CDay("Thursday"),
            new CDay("Friday")
        });
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]        
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(List<CDay> days)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ... you_code here 
    }
    var model = new DaysViewModel() { Days = days };
    return View(model);
}
```

**Test screen shots**

The view:

[image]

On the controller side:

[image]

Comment: hmm I don't understand how I would know which checkbox would be clicked if my viewmodel doesn't include  : public bool Monday { get; set; }

Comment: doesn't it depend on the name of checkbox so viewmodel knows which chekcbox was clicked? in this case the name of the checkbox is Monday @victor

Comment: @lillyk: First, list of the days will returned to the controller in the same order as they was passed to the view. Second, each day object has it name. I have added a screen shot to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `jQuery`

Add a `button` bellow your checkboxes

`<input type="button" value="Your_Value" class="btn btn-default" />`

When click on a `button` create a post request and sends checked status via `querystring`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
        var queryString = 'Monday=' + $("input[name=Monday]").is(":checked") + '&Tuesday=' + $("input[name=Tuesday]").is(":checked") + '&Wednesday=' + $("input[name=Wednesday]").is(":checked") + '&Thursday=' + $("input[name=Thursday]").is(":checked") + '&Friday=' + $("input[name=Friday]").is(":checked");
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Home/Edit?" + queryString,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And inside `controller` create `Edit Post Method` like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult checkboxespost(string Monday, string Tuesday, string Wednesday, string Thursday, string Friday)
{
    ...
}
```